# (Soft) Lay Survey of human natural history

Tags: evolution, human-evolution, book-recommendation

I am looking for an introduction to the natural history of humans. I had originally thought *Sapiens* until I found out it is more a history and archeology book of dubious scientific accuracy. The Sorts of things I am interested in are: Neanderthal interbreeding, human canine bond, comparison of human with other primates.

If this is off topic, I am sorry. There was a similar question already posted some time ago, but the answers seems outdated.

Comment: Can you link to the previous question and note the ways in which it did not sufficiently address your question? Was it only because of time? Those are still some broad topics.

Comment: A general overview would be accomplished by a text book, however some of what you are asking about is rather in depth concepts I doubt you will find them covered in detail in the same book. the issue with newer science is it takes a while for it to be collected in a single textbook so you may have to search of each topic individually.  this site may at least help get you started with terminology. https://www2.palomar.edu/anthro/hominid/australo_2.htm